# Linux - Network Sharing a local NTFS usb drive

Tags: linux, samba, network-shares, ntfs

I have an external hard drive formated in NTFS which I would like to be able to access by the network. I want to make a network share out of it.

I also have a Debian machine running in my house and I then got an idea.

I want to plug in my external hard drive (usb) into my Debian machine, and make a windows share with it, maybe with Samba, so I will be able to access it from my Windows 7 laptop and see it as a network share.

Additionally, how can I restrict specific folders of that network share, and allow only specific folders to specific users? For instance, I would like to give my girlfriend access to a folder of her name so she can put her files and so she wont be able to see the stuff in my folder...

Answer (score 1):

Samba is exactly the tool to use.  With Samba you expose directories as NTFS shares, and they are accessed just as you would a native Windows share.

If the share in Samba is not configured as accessible by `guest ok` then the user must provide credentials to access the share.  In a basic setup, these credentials map to linux user accounts, and so you can use standard linux permissions to control access to different directories.

There are many tutorials available, [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/340) one should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

To set it up within 15 minutes, use any graphical samba administration tool.
e.g. system-config-samba, SWAT, Smb4K.

[This](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/1060-how-to-configure-samba-using-a-graphical-interface-in-ubuntu) is a very useful link for you.

Comment: I dont have the graphical interface :(